# Asp.Net Html.editorFor foreign id convert to name from a different table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.countyid, new {@class = "control-label"})
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.countyid, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.countyid)
</div>
```

My main table has a foreign key for the countyid which links to the county table. Above is my editor for the countyid.

Problem -  I need to convert the id into a list of the names from the other table so that the user isn't shown these id numbers. If I could have some help with the theory of this and maybe an example from a similar problem, it would be most appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: Specifics - my first table has other data but a foreign key is county id. The county table has id and name and I need to pull name into the same form that I'm using for my first table replacing the id and then sending back the id from the name chosen.

Models: County

```
public partial class County
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int countryid { get; set; }
    public bool deleted { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Company:

```
public partial class Agency
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool deleted { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address1 { get; set; }
    public string address2 { get; set; }
    public string address3 { get; set; }
    public string town { get; set; }
    public int countyid { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public string telephoneno { get; set; }
    public string companyno { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the data from the tables?

Comment: I'm getting a list from the database, converting to json and inserting into a table tag from controller. I'm also using a plugin which displays the data in a nice table with pagination and search

Comment: and for the html doc, the main model for the form is being passed into it like @model models.company

Comment: If you have a query that you are using to get the list, can you please post it too?

Comment: var agencies = _db.Agencies.ToList();

Comment: return Json(new { data = agencies,draw = Request["draw"], recordsTotal = totalRows, recordsFiltered = recordsAfterFilter }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: that second comment is more to do with the plugin. the list is passed to "data" where "data=agencies"

Comment: Is there a _db.Counties.ToList() that returns the list of counties?

Comment: Not atm, there can be, however the data is passed to the html form which can only take one model so I don't really know how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

Your model should have more than just the id in it:

```
 public class CountyInfo{
        public int countyid {get;set;}
        public string CountyName{get;set;}
        //Whatever other properties you want in the model to use on the page
}
```

Since you said a list of ids, I'm assuming you want to pull multiple records at a time from the db model like this and map what you get from your tables to it:

```
public class CountyInfoList{
        public List<CountyInfo> Counties {get;set;}
        //other props that go to counties in general
}
```

Then you can add this to your main model

```
public class PrimaryTableModel {
       public int PrimaryTableID {get;set;}
       //if there's a one to one relationship between primary table and county
       public CountyInfo County {get;set;}
       //or if there's a many to one relationship 
       public CountyInfoList CountiesList {get;set;}
 }
```

I don't think you mean to use the Id field in the editor. If this is a object you are editing, have the id hidden above. It should be like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.countyid)
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.CountyName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
```

or if using the primary table model

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.County.countyid)
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.County.CountyName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})

 @foreach (var c in Model.CountiesList.Counties )
        {
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>c.countyid)
@Html.EditorFor(model => c.CountyName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific, my first table has other data but a foreign key is county id. The county table has id and name and I need to pull name into the same form that I'm using for my first table. Thanks for the reply too

Comment: My table are all seperate models and I'm passing my first model into the html document already so I don't think I can pass the second table to the same form. I'm also using MVC. hopefully that answers your question